# How to calculate by adding the date_time to duration in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have a table with column of pickup_time , duration(number of minutes it took to deliver the order).

How can I add and calculate the duration to pickup_time column and get new delivered column as a deliverd_time
Here is the example

> ```
> pickup_time            duration
>
> 2023-01-01 18:00:00        32
> ```

I have tried to use datediff or dateadd but couldn't get the results.

I expect a new column such as delivered_time*

> ```
> Delivered_time
>
> 2023-01-01 18:32:00
> ```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question, it's unclear what you wish to ask here. also please read: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: And it is really not necessary to SHOUT AT US :)

Comment: Hi @shailaja,  I notice pickup_time in your description is '2023-01-01 18:00:0' instead of '2023-01-01 18:00:00'.  there is one missing '0' at the end. Is this a typo or an intended representation?

Comment: "I have tried to use datediff or dateadd but couldn't get the results" - and no SQL query in your question showing how you tried that and failed. Then it basically sounds like "please write a query for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, You can use [DATE_ADD()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) and INTERVAL to build the desired query.

See the following code as an example:

```
SELECT
    pickup_time,
    duration,
    DATE_ADD(pickup_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS delivered_time
FROM
    delivery_data
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ce4d/2)

| pickup_time | duration | delivered_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01T18:00:00Z | 32 | 2023-01-01T18:32:00Z |